# RESTEasy UnavailableException HttpServletDispatcher

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, resteasy, embedded-jetty

I searched and tried for hours to solve this problem, unfortunately without success.

I am using Java 1.6, RESTEasy 2.2.1.GA and a Jetty Embedded Server to setup a webservice.
Originally I copied an existing working project to set this one up. Somehow the original project works, my adjusted copy doesnt work.

After starting the Embedded Server I get the following exception:

Here is what the console says:

```
2011-10-27 09:22:51.113::INFO:  Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
2011-10-27 09:22:51.141::INFO:  jetty-6.0.2
2011-10-27 09:22:51.352::WARN:  failed Resteasy
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:78)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:229)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:574)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:128)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1219)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:421)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:496)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:228)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at com.xtag.locationadapter.webui.EmbeddedServer.main(EmbeddedServer.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
2011-10-27 09:22:51.398::WARN:  Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@1c5d9084{/admin,file:/Users/workspace/LocationAdapter/webui/target/classes/com/company/locationadapter/webui/webapp/}
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:78)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:229)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:574)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:128)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1219)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:421)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:496)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:228)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:40)
    at com.xtag.locationadapter.webui.EmbeddedServer.main(EmbeddedServer.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
2011-10-27 09:22:51.400::INFO:  Started SocketConnector @ 0.0.0.0:8088
```

This is my project structure. Please ignore the fact that the name webui doesnt fit to the content of this folder.:

```
   LocationAdapter
    - .idea
    - .settings
    - bin
    - webui
    |- src
      |- main
        |- java
           |- com.company.locationadapter.communication.rest
             |- ResteasyApplication.java
           |- com.company.locationadapter.communication.restservices
             |- LocationResource.java
             |- LocationResourceImpl.java
           |- com.company.locationadapter.service
             |- LocationService.java
             |- LocationServiceImpl.java
           |- com.company.locationadapter.webui
             |- EmbeddedServer.java
        |- resources
           |- com.company.locationadapter.webui.webapp
             |- dummy.html
           |- com.company.locationadapter.webui.webapp.WEB-INF
             |- web.xml
```

My ResteasyApplication Class:

```
public class ResteasyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        Set<Object> set = new HashSet<Object>();
        set.add(new LocationResourceImpl());
        return set;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return super.getClasses();
    }
}
```

My EmbeddedServer Class:

```
public class EmbeddedServer {

    private static final String WEBAPP = "com/company/locationadapter/webui/webapp";
    private static final String CONTEXT_PATH = "/admin";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        addSystemProperties();
        final Server server = new Server(8088);
        final URL warUrl = EmbeddedServer.class.getClassLoader().getResource(WEBAPP);
        final String warUrlString = warUrl.toExternalForm();
        server.setHandler(new WebAppContext(warUrlString, CONTEXT_PATH));
        server.start();
    }

    protected static void addSystemProperties() {
        try {
            Properties properties = new Properties(System.getProperties());
            String path = System.getProperty("user.properties");
            properties.load(new FileInputStream(new File(path)));
            System.setProperties(properties);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The web.xml for configuration of RESTEasy:

```
<web-app>

    <display-name>LocationAdapter</display-name>
    <description>Company</description>

    <context-param>
          <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
          <param-value>/locationadapter</param-value>
    </context-param>

     <servlet>
         <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>
             org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
         </servlet-class>
         <init-param>
             <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
             <param-value>com.company.locationadapter.communication.rest.ResteasyApplication</param-value>
         </init-param>
     </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

</web-app>
```

I would really appreciate, if someone have an idea or solution for this exception. 
If you need further information please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved, the exception was caused by an entry in the POM.xml, where the scope of the artifact "resteasy-jaxb-provider" was set to provided